# Interacting with the smart contract from Java application (We3j)

Tags: contract-invocation, testrpc, web3j, java

I have many questions about the workflow ( sequence ) of interacting with the smart contract from Java application, so I will first explain what I have done and then put my questions, and if something wrong in my understanding please let me know.

1- I have written smart contract 
2- Use truffle to get the smart contract java wrapper.(contract.java)
3- Use testrpc to test the contract

I have 2 class uses testrpc accounts (credentials) to interact with the smart contract and call its functions

Each class (node1.java, node2.java) call a function in the smart contract called (send) to  send their data to the chain.

I have added an event which trigger if the 2 nodes have sent there data

What I don't understand is, how I can let the java code ( Let say MainProgram.class) always check for that event. Because I need to check if both nodes send their data, then I will call another function to analyse this data.

How I can manage, control and check what transactions have been done or not, I mean how I can use the events in java code and let the code run forever and check if the this event happen, do action.

Hope I can explain what I need clearly

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just add one more thing, if my understanding is correct and I need a MainProgram class to control and check the events then I need to use one of testrpc account to run this code. This means this program is considered as a node in the chain and play as the manager for the network, so the smart contract isn't the control !!

Comment: Am not java developer, but see if this answer here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/41534/20357 gives you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

In your java wrapper for each type of event in your SmartContract, there will be a function that looks like this:

```
public Observable<ApprovalEventResponse> approvalEventObservable(DefaultBlockParameter startBlock, DefaultBlockParameter endBlock) {

            ...                

            return typedResponse;
        }
    });
}
```

You can subscribe to this observable from your java code as follows:

```
contract.approvalEventObservable(DefaultBlockParameter.valueOf("Earliest"),DefaultBlockParameter.valueOf("Latest")).asObservable().subscribe( event ->{
    System.out.prtinln(event._approver);
});
```

This will replay all events that have occurred and print the attribute of previous events and will also print new events when they occur.