# JSON RPC + web3: Subscribe to Solidity events

Tags: web3js, json-rpc, web3-providers

When using web3 and the JSON RPC, is there a way to subscribe to Solidity events?  For instance, I want to subscribe to every

```
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
```

sent from the contract at address `0x123whatever`.

Ideally, I could do this using a hosted JSON RPC provider, and not by running my own node.  But if it's impossible on a hosted provider, I might begrudgingly accept instructions for how to do it running my own node.

Answer (score 1):

The code below works with Metamask if you want to subscribe to events and show them on browser

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
          web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        }
else
{
   console.log('Metamask not found');return;
}
var abi = [YOUR_CONTRACT_ABI_GOES_HERE];
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
        var myContractInstance = MyContract.at("YOUR_CONTRACT_ADDRESS");
var transferEevent = myContractInstance.Transfer({"to":"TO_ADDRESS"},{fromBlock: FROM_BLOCK_NUMBER, toBlock: 'latest'});
transferEevent.watch(function(error, response) {

                 if (!error) {
                console.log(response); // you check args like response.args.fromAddress if you created the event parameter
                 } else {
                      console.error(error);
                 }
            });
```